# Access rails 2.2.2 config in an initializer file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, config, ruby-on-rails-2

I have a couple of lines in my `config/environments/production.rb` environment file for a rails 2.2.2 app, which only do anything when i'm running on my local machine:

```
if ENV['HOME'] == "/home/max"
  #fall back to the default logger instead of hodel, locally
  config.logger = nil
  #put sql into a seperate log 
  config.active_record.logger = Logger.new("log/sql.log")
end
```

Having this in the app's production environment file feels pretty dirty.  I've got another file, `config/initializers/max_local/send_mails_from_max_gmail.rb`, which configures outgoing emails to use a gmail account, and does a couple of other me-specific things on startup.

Moving my logger config into there seems like a better option than having it in the production.rb file: for a start, the `send_mails_from_max_gmail.rb` file is git-ignored so no-one else ever sees it.

But, i can't figure out how to get to the rails config in there.  It doesn't have the `config` local variable, which existed in the block generated by `Rails::Initializer.run do |config|`.  How do i get at this config?

thanks, Max

**EDIT**:  detailed reply to @japed's answer below, which requires some formatting and so is nicer here than in a comment.  I'm just going to focus on `config.active_record.logger = Logger.new("log/sql.log")`, which moves the sql output into log/sql.log instead of the standard log.

I've tried the following:
changed production.rb as follows:  note that the logger line is commented out:

```
puts "production.rb:#{__LINE__} : config.active_record.logger = #{config.active_record.logger.inspect}"
#config.active_record.logger = Logger.new("log/sql.log")
```

Added the following to `config/initializers/max_local/send_mails_from_max_gmail.rb`:

```
puts "send_mails_from_max_gmail.rb:#{__LINE__} : Rails.configuration.active_record.logger = #{Rails.configuration.active_record.logger.inspect}"
Rails.configuration.active_record.logger = Logger.new("log/sql.log")
puts "send_mails_from_max_gmail.rb:#{__LINE__} : Rails.configuration.active_record.logger = #{Rails.configuration.active_record.logger.inspect}"
```

Then, i've restarted my server.  i can see this output:

```
production.rb:65 : config.active_record.logger = nil
send_mails_from_max_gmail.rb:42 : Rails.configuration.active_record.logger = nil
send_mails_from_max_gmail.rb:44 : Rails.configuration.active_record.logger = #<Logger:0x7fcbee0fedc8 @formatter=nil, @progname=nil, @level=0, @logdev=#<Logger::LogDevice:0x7fcbee0fed28 @dev=#<File:log/sql.log>, @filename="log/sql.log", @mutex=#<Logger::LogDevice::LogDeviceMutex:0x7fcbee0fecd8 @mon_waiting_queue=[], @mon_entering_queue=[], @mon_count=0, @mon_owner=nil>, @shift_size=1048576, @shift_age=0>, @default_formatter=#<Logger::Formatter:0x7fcbee0fed78 @datetime_format=nil>>
```

which looks like it's working, and the the override is happening after the main config runs.  But, the sql isn't going into log/sql.log, it's going into the standard production.log

Answer (score 0):

Ok, diving into the docs and in rails 2 `Rails.logger` maps to the constant `RAILS_DEFAULT_LOGGER` [docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v2.3.8/classes/Rails.html)

So you should be able to do

```
if ENV['HOME'] == "/home/max"
  RAILS_DEFAULT_LOGGER = Logger.new("log/sql.log")
end
```

This time properly tested in console

```
RAILS_DEFAULT_LOGGER = Logger.new("log/sql.log")
=> warning: already initialized constant RAILS_DEFAULT_LOGGER

>> Rails.logger.info "Blah"
=> true
```

And I get Blah in `log/sql.log`

Comment: I should point out I tried this in console, not in an initializer.  I figure it *should* work.

Comment: This doesn't work for me in the console actually.  Would you mind expanding on your answer with exactly what you did in the console and how you tested whether it had worked?  (in case i'm missing something)  thanks!

Comment: Yeah, I only looked into setting it then assumed it would work after that, sorry. I'm guessing it's setting the configuration but that's loaded once when Rails boots which is why it's not working.

Comment: @MaxWilliams updated my answer having had a bit more of a fiddle around.  Actually viewing the output this works for me in console now.

Comment: That pushes all of the standard logging into log/sql.log, but what i was trying to do (and what the original code in production.rb does) is push the SQL into `log/sql.log` and leave the rest into the regular log.

Comment: I just tried this `ActiveRecord::Base.logger = Logger.new("log/sql.log")  ` and that didn't work either.

Comment: That was going to be my next suggestion :(  Doing that in console worked for me - in terms of logging the sql to sql.log.  Does it still log it to development too?

Comment: Yep, sql and regular logging are just going to the main log.   Are you trying this in a rails 2.2.2 console?

Comment: Rails 2.3, I don't have any apps on 2.2.2 I'm afraid

Comment: Hmm, maybe something changed between 2.2.2 and 2.3 then.

Comment: BTW - when i said " sql and regular logging are just going to the main log" that was after doing `ActiveRecord::Base.logger = Logger.new("log/sql.log")`, ie this didn't seem to do anything.   When i did `RAILS_DEFAULT_LOGGER = Logger.new("log/sql.log")` then regular logging and sql all go to  `log/sql.log`

Comment: I'm starting to think that it might be easier to leave it as it is, in production.rb.